# Vue.js 2 : change a template but keep logic of a component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

### I want to create a component from an other component and change the template in some part but keep all the logic of the component.

I want to have all the event passed automatically to my parent component (maybe use extends ?).

For example I have a child1 use by child2, child2 use by child3, and child3 use by child4.

If I add a $emit in child1, I don't want to add $emit in child2, child3 and child4 to passed my child1 event to child4

I give a code below to show an example of 2 childs.
Imagine I have 10 childs and want to add 5 new $emit('event').

```js
var child = Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div @click="clickOnChild">' +
  '<slot name="header"></slot>' +
  'Before content !' +
  '<slot name="content"></slot>' +
  'After content !' +
  '<slot name="footer"></slot></div>',
  methods: {
   clickOnChild: function() {
     this.$emit('childClicked', 'Hello from child !');
    }
  }
});

var child2 = Vue.component('child2', {
  template: '<child @childClicked="childHasBeenClicked">' +
  '<h1 slot="header">My title header !</h1>' +
  '<p slot="content">My content !</p>' +
  '<p slot="footer">My footer !</p>' +
  '</child>',
  components: { child },
  methods: {
   childHasBeenClicked: function( event ){
     alert( event );
    }
  }
});
  
new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  components: { child2 },
  data: {
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  <child2></child2>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a mixin to share code between components. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I will see mixin.